# conduit and wire size needed

Tags: electrical, wiring, conduit

Looking to hook up a new 20KW generator to an existing manual 200A transfer switch.

What size copper wire do I need (2 hot legs, 1 neutral and one ground) and what size PVC conduit do I need for all 4 wires? The distance from the generator to the transfer switch is 15 feet

Comment: Any reason not to use EMT for such a short distance? Handles your ground for you, one less wire...

Comment: And why copper, for that matter?  You're talking fat enough wires that aluminum makes sense here...

Comment: I use cu. wire and also use penatrox (sp) on the connections and also PVC because of outside connections and what other conduit is already in use

Answer (score 1):

[Oracle says](http://www.southwire.com/support/voltage-drop-calculator.htm) #1 aluminum.   Or #3 copper if you own a copper mine.

I don't like copper because the lugs on both ends are usually aluminum, and I don't like mixing copper and aluminum due to dissimilar metal corrosion.  You may recall that caused a national scandal when shoddy receptacles intended only for copper were used on aluminum wire.

Comment: @Tyson Oh, that'll be Safari.  Hard to copy/paste URLs.

Answer (score 0):

3 AWG copper should do it.  Use http://wiresizecalculator.net/ to calculate wire sizes.

1 AWG Aluminum would be more common in this case.

Comment: 20kva /240= 83.3 × 125% =104A where do you get 3/0?

Comment: My bad.  I used 200A instead of 20kva.  I'll update to reflect 104A, but where did you get 240?

Comment: 240v is the standard for calculations. I used 125% on wire size since I don't know if the generator has a breaker/ overload protection. My local code is disconnecting means 115% and wire size 125% unless the manufacture instructions allows 100% wire size. 445.13 = 115% conductors

Comment: Took two long to find it and edit comment NEC 445.13 ampacity of conductors from generator terminals to distribution device 115%.